# Rewrite Rule to redirect for media files

Tags: regex, .htaccess

We recently moved a site to a new domain and now need to redirect any requests for pdf files.

All pdfs are now stored in one folder on the new server called "oldmedia" so we need to redirect all requests for pdfs to the new folder.

Essentially, all old links look like this: http://olddomain.com/Publications/file.pdf

And they need to be redirected to http://newdomain.com/oldmedia/file.pdf

All pdf urls will be coming from the Publications sub-directory so we've been trying to check "if it starts with Publications and ends with .pdf", but I can't get it to work.

Here's what I have so far:

`RewriteRule ^(/Publications/)[.+](\.pdf)$ oldmedia/$2.pdf [R=301, NC, L]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^Publications/([^/]+\.pdf)$ http://newdomain.com/oldmedia/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If the rule is in the root of `olddomain.com`.